# execcomand fault in opera

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, opera, execcommand

recently i had to use execCommand() in Opera. The problem is this, when i try to change background color (or text color) with this function, everything works as expected, but when i mix more colors than one there is unexpected behaviour. I have made a test page to understand what i mean:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changecolor(color) {
 document.execCommand ('ForeColor', false, color);
 document.getElementById('source').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
}       
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="changecolor('red');">Red</button>
    <button onclick="changecolor('blue');">Blue</button>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="content">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>

    <textarea id="source" style="margin-top:100px;width:800px;height:200px;"></textarea>
</body>
```

(See [in action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBas2/))

So, try mix up the two colors with latest version of Opera and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where to mix which colors? Some seem to work, some not.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm seeing: When the selection spans more than one color and ends inside the same colour you try to apply, nothing happens. When it ends inside a different colour, some of the old colour is removed but the new one isn't applied.

It sounds similar to Opera's existing bug CORE-24880 "execCommand('bold') should make the selection bold even if part of the selection is bold". I'll follow up this bug and try to push it closer to a fix.

Comment: Do you have any links to look for this bug?

Comment: Sorry, Opera's bug tracker is closed so you can't watch it. The good news is that I work for Opera, so I can. Apologies for the closed-source development process.

Comment: Are there any other sources i can look for?

Comment: Well, you can keep an eye on the changelogs posted on http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/ - if you see that bug number mentioned it should be fixed..